# Cart to Fly Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a cart fly effect but I am getting an error and not sure why the top is being called undefined. I am already able to add the product on the basket but the image just got stuck and appears randomly on screen instead of animation from the parent image to the cart upward

```
$('.add').on('click', function () {
        var cart = $('.cart');
        var imgtodrag = $('.zoomImg');
        if (imgtodrag) {
            var imgclone = imgtodrag.clone()
                .offset({
                top: imgtodrag.offset().top,
                left: imgtodrag.offset().left
            })
                .css({
                'opacity': '0.5',
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'height': '150px',
                    'width': '150px',
                    'z-index': '100'
            })
                .appendTo($('body'))
                .animate({
                'top': cart.offset().top + 10,
                    'left': cart.offset().left + 10,
                    'width': 75,
                    'height': 75
            }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');

            setTimeout(function () {
                cart.effect("shake", {
                    times: 2
                }, 200);
            }, 1500);

            imgclone.animate({
                'width': 0,
                    'height': 0
            }, function () {
                $(this).detach()
            });
        }
    });
```

P.S.
I am using Jquery 2.1.3 and jqueryui 1.11.2

Answer (score 0):

already figured it out, the element was missing on some page causing the error